# How to access main method variables from scalatest-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am couple of days into scala programming

I was playing with the scala code here

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

    object SimpleApp {
      def main(args:Array[String]) {
        val logFile = "../samplelog.txt"
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
        val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
        val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()

        def getNumAs : Long = numAs
        def getNumBs : Long = numBs

        println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
      }
    }
```

My scalatest is as follows

```
import org.scalatest._

    class simpleAppTest extends FunSuite with Matchers {

    test ("number of a's and b's")

    val acount=SimpleApp.numAs
    val bcount=SimpleApp.numBs

    acount should be(2)
    bcount should be(1)


    }
```

The issue is that I am unable to get values of getnumAs and getnumBs. The compiler complains that getnumAs/getnumBs is not a value of unit. I tried looking for scaladocs or sample code but have no clue on how to resolve this.

kindly help

thanks

Comment: Why `def app`, not `object app`? def does not have member values, object has. The way you have it now, `def app {...}` is actually `def app: Unit = {...}`

Comment: @Suma , I have edited the code to consider the main method, now how to get values of numsA and numsB? There is no global variable concept in scala.

Comment: @Suma, went over through tutorials, have to declare them as fields of the object SimpleApp. thanks for the help